# Synchronous spawn in node.js

Tags: node.js

I would like to create a child process in node, and block in a fiber until the process has terminated. They way I have understood it, it should look something like this:

```
var child_process = require ("child_process");
var Fiber = require ("fibers");
var Future = require ("fibers/future");

var ls = Fiber (function () {
    var lsproc = child_process.spawn ("ls");
    var lsonSync = Future.wrap (lsproc.on);

    console.log ("return: " + lsonSync ("exit").wait ());
}).run ();
```

The response from node is:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'emit'
```

I assume this has something to do with the fact that I am wrapping an instance method instead of a function, but I am not sure how proceed.

Comment: Why don't you use processes instead? Fibers represents kind of everything Node.js opposes.

Comment: @alessioalex I'm trying out meteor which runs in node on the server, but everything is wrapped in fibers and written in a synchronous style .

Comment: Ah I see. I would try to use something like DerbyJS instead or make my own framework (but that's just my opinion).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes you need to ask the question for the answer to pop into your head.

Binding the `on`-method to `lsproc` before wrapping it in a future solves the problem:

```
var child_process = require ("child_process");
var Fiber = require ("fibers");
var Future = require ("fibers/future");

var ls = Fiber (function () {
    var lsproc = child_process.spawn ("ls", ["/etc"]);
    var lsonSync = Future.wrap (lsproc.on.bind (lsproc));

    console.log ("return: " + lsonSync ("exit").wait ());
}).run ();
```

Comment: _Sometimes you need to ask the question for the answer to pop into your head_ +1